# Is NULL function different between SQL and VS 2005 (C#)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have demonstrate following SQL between SQL and VS 2005:

```
update expbill set convrate=null
where transID=2
and companyID=114
```

The above T-SQL is working fine on SQL Server and updates the rows as NULL, but the same transaction is not working in VS 2005, using this SQL query:

```
string update_exp = " update expbill set convrate = " + null + "" +
                " where companyID = '" + label1.Text + "'" + 
                " and invno = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
SqlCommand updated_cmd  = new SqlCommand(update_exp , con);
updated_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The above SQL query throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near the key words
>   “where”

I want to know that if the same SQL statement works in SQL but not in Visual Studio. Is there any difference of NULL function between SQL and VS 2005??

Comment: null is converted to string.empty

Comment: You should **NEVER** ever concatenate together your SQL statements in C# - [can you spell "SQL Injection attacks" ??](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record:

```
string update_exp = @"
update expbill set convrate=@rate
where companyID=@cid
and invno=@iid";
SqlCommand updated_cmd  = new SqlCommand(update_exp , connection);
updated_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rate", DBNull.Value);
updated_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cid", label1.Text);
updated_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("iid", textBox1.Text);
updated_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will keep you safe. DO NOT CONCATENATE TEXT TO MAKE SQL. If that is typical of your coding style, I need you to realise that your code is *dangerously exposed* and can be abused and broken accidentally or maliciously. Pain. Lots of pain.

Comment: nice solution but I think you are missing parameter sign on supplying the value and connection should not remain "null"

Comment: @magesh the null was my debug, sorry

Comment: @mahesh you do not need an @ in the names in the managed code. In fact it is better not to

Answer (score 4):

NULL is a keyword/symbol in SQL

```
string update_exp = " update expbill set convrate = NULL " +
```

The c# null is very different

Edit:

The equivalent would be [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) but I've never tried to concatenate it...

Comment: the DBNull.Value also not work for it. The both are totally diferent from sql transact.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this. You don't have to pass in a c# `null`. Just use SQL's.

```
string update_exp = " update expbill set convrate = null +
                    " where companyID='" + label1.Text + "'"+ 
                    " and invno='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Both mean "nothing". But if you pass C#'s `null` into a string object, your built-up SQL statement would have read

> update expbill set convrate =
>    where companyid = 'somevalue' 
>    and invno = 'someOthervalue'

Hence the "Incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'"

Comment: tobias86, nice answer but still some thing missing ther "why?".

Comment: ... well null is a keyword in both sql and vs-2005 it is working same on sql why not in c#?.

Comment: @mahesh it is a different language and means different things. In C#, "abc" + null + "def" is "abcdef".

Comment: @Marc, nice to see you here this question's main purpose is to sort out the above null keyword between two different languages as there are many things between them to match but here null keyword is defer as diferent languages.

Comment: ... and it is the my answer that c# null keyword is not supported to sql null keyword as diferent language. thanks marc

Comment: @tobias86 there are error on your sql transaction alter it to accept me the answer. the error of sign "".

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
string update_exp = " update expbill set convrate = null "+
                " where companyID='" + label1.Text + "'"+ 
                " and invno='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is SQL interpret a text, and (as Piotr Auguscik said) null converts to empty string, your SQL will be broken in the convertion, it is not about the null, it is about the SQL text creation.